# How to get result as only object without any string prefix in loopback framework at NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

**Technology** : NodeJS

**Framework** : Loopback v4

I'm trying to get a record from db but returns result like this :

***code***:

```
console.log(await this.userRepository.findOne(filter));
```

***result***:

```
User {
  id: undefined,
  createdOn: undefined,
  createdBy: undefined,
  updatedOn: undefined,
  updatedBy: undefined,
  username: 'string',
  password: undefined,
  firstName: 'string',
  lastName: 'string',
  gender: true,
  birthDate: undefined
}
```

***expected***

```
{
  id: undefined,
  createdOn: undefined,
  createdBy: undefined,
  updatedOn: undefined,
  updatedBy: undefined,
  username: 'string',
  password: undefined,
  firstName: 'string',
  lastName: 'string',
  gender: true,
  birthDate: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
let obj = await this.userRepository.findOne(filter);

let result = obj.toJSON();
```